# Send mail from django form wizard

Tags: python, django, forms, email, wizard

I have any models and the view to generate a form wizard, once the user submit the last form, I want the app send a confirmation email, the current user's mail is in the native Django model, how I can access to his email? and how I can access to "curso" name too? thanks for your help.

**models.py**

```
class Datos_Basicos (models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    tipo_identificacion = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    identificacion = models.CharField(max_length=20,primary_key='True')
    telefono = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    celular = models.CharField(max_length=11)

class Curso(models.Model):
    curso = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    fk_programa = models.ForeignKey(Programa, verbose_name="programa")

class Inscripcion(models.Model):
    fecha = models.DateField(default = datetime.datetime.now)
    fk_subsede = models.ForeignKey(Subsede, verbose_name="sede")
    fk_curso = models.ForeignKey(Curso, verbose_name="curso")

class Inscrito(models.Model):
    fk_datos_basicos = models.OneToOneField(Datos_Basicos, verbose_name="datos basicos")        
    fk_inscripcion = models.OneToOneField(Inscripcion, verbose_name="curso", null=False)
```

**forms.py**

```
class Datos_basicos_form(forms.ModelForm):
      tipo_identificacion = forms.ChoiceField(choices=IDENTIFICACION_CHOICES)

   class Meta:
    model = Datos_Basicos
    fields = ['tipo_identificacion', 'identificacion', 'telefono', 'celular'] 


class Inscrito_form(forms.Form):
    genero = forms.ChoiceField(choices=GENEROS_CHOICES)
    fecha_nacimiento = forms.DateField(widget=extras.SelectDateWidget(years=ANIOS_CHOICES))
    grupo_etnico = forms.ChoiceField(choices=GRUPO_ETNICO_CHOICES)
    condicion = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Condicion.objects.all())
    condicion_medica = forms.CharField(max_length=200)
    eps = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    espacio_geografico = forms.ChoiceField(choices=ESPACIO_GEOGRAFICO_CHOICES)
    barrio = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Barrio.objects.order_by('barrio'))
    direccion = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
    jornada_estudio = forms.ChoiceField(choices=JORNADA_ESTUDIO_CHOICES)


class Inscripcion_form(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Inscripcion
        exclude = ['fecha']
```

**views.py**

```
from formtools.wizard.views import SessionWizardView

class InscritoWizard(SessionWizardView):
    template_name = "inscripcion.html"


    def done(self, form_list, **kwargs):
        forms_data = self.process_form_data(form_list)
        forms_data[1]['user'] = self.request.user ### current user
        forms_data[2]['edad'] = hoy.year - forms_data[2]['fecha_nacimiento'].year - ((hoy.month, hoy.day) < (forms_data[2]['fecha_nacimiento'].month, forms_data[2]['fecha_nacimiento'].day))
        inscripcion = Inscripcion.objects.create(**forms_data[0])
        datos_basicos = Datos_Basicos.objects.create(**forms_data[1])
        forms_data[2]['fk_datos_basicos'] = datos_basicos
        forms_data[2]['fk_inscripcion'] = inscripcion
        Inscrito.objects.create(**forms_data[2])
    --->send_mail('Subject here', 'Here is the message.','from@example.com',['to@example.com'], fail_silently=False)
        return render_to_response('gracias.html', {'forms_data': forms_data})

    def process_form_data(self, form_list):
        data = [form.cleaned_data for form in form_list]
        return data
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the form wizard methods, you can access the logged in user with `self.request.user`, therefore you can get their email with `self.request.user.email`.

Comment: Hey thanks, how I can access an object from other model, for example "Curso" model has an attribute "curso" and it's a fk in "Inscripcion" model, 
I'm tryng    forms_data[2]['fk_inscripcion'].fk_curso.curso, I can't understand how I can acces to object.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the structure of your `forms_data` because it's quite complex. You haven't shown what your forms are. What is `forms_data[2]['fk_inscripcion']` - is it a model instance, or a primary key?

Comment: forms_data is a dictionary of objects created from form data submitted this expression: forms_data[2] reffers the form in question, in this case: forms_data[2] is some like this: {'fk_inscripcion', 'date','other','bla bla' }, so I can access to "date" for example this way: forms_data[2]['date']. But I need to access to an object that I can access through "fk_inscripcion".

Comment: As I asked before, what is the value of `forms_data[2]['fk_inscripcion']`? Is it a model instance, or a primary key?

Comment: `forms_data[2]['fk_inscripcion']` is a primary key

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand your forms. Hope you figure it out.